# How do I modify these group of functions to get everything left of #?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column that has values stored in the following format:

name#URL

All data is stored with this and a second # is never present.

I've got the following statement that strips the URL from this column:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING ( wf_name ,PATINDEX ( '%#%' , wf_name )+1 , LEN(wf_name)-(PATINDEX ( '%#%' , wf_name )) )
```

However I want to take the name also (everything left of the #). Unfortuantely I don't understand the functions I'm using above (having read the  documentation I'm still confused). Could somebody please help me to understand the flow and how I can adjust this to get everything left of #?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following example

```
; WITH Table1 AS (
    SELECT  'TADA#TEST' AS NameURL
)
SELECT  *,
        LEFT(NameURL,PATINDEX('%#%',NameURL) - 1) LeftText,
        RIGHT(NameURL,PATINDEX('%#%',NameURL)- 1) RightText
FROM    Table1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5618)

Using functions

[PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

> Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in
>   a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found, on all
>   valid text and character data types.

[LEFT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)

> Returns the left part of a character string with the specified number
>   of characters.

[RIGHT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)

> Returns the right part of a character string with the specified number
>   of characters.